# Spring XML Configuration - How to specify property value for a group of objects?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Say I have the following beans defined.

```
<bean id="testBean1" class="org.springframework.beans.TestBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="hariColor" value="Black"/>
    <property name="spouse">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.TestBean">
            <property name="age" value="11"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="testBean2" class="org.springframework.beans.TestBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="hariColor" value="Black"/>
    <property name="spouse">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.TestBean">
            <property name="age" value="19"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have a set of beans with hairColor Black, another set of beans with hairColor Blonde etc.. Is there a way in Spring to group all Black hair color beans together and define the hairColor in only one place rather than specifying for each bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve it via `abstract="true"` element in Spring's bean as explained below

```
<bean id="blackHairColor" abstract="true">
    <property name="prop1" ref="someBlackBean"/>
    <property name="prop2" ref="someOtherBlackBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="blondeHairColor" abstract="true">
    <property name="prop1" ref="someBlondeBean"/>
    <property name="prop2" ref="someOtherBlondeBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="someBean1" class="a.b.c.d" parent="blackHairColor">
    <property name="someOtherProp" ref="someRef1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="someBean2" class="a.b.c.d" parent="blondeHairColor">
    <property name="someOtherProp" ref="someRef1"/>
</bean>
```

Here we define two `abstract` beans with respective properties. Do note that these `abstract` beans do not have a `class` attached to them and thus creates a *set of common properties* which could be re-used in other bean(s).

To inherit the `abstract` bean simply mention their id in the `parent` element of bean definition. Also note that the bean class does not need to inherit any class to inherit another bean i.e. class `a.b.c.d` do not need to inherit any class for the bean inheritance to work.